# Unable to install Composer Cli

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to install HyperLedger Composer in CentOS 7. I tried installing with sudo and without sudo. Its not working.

```
    [srisris@localhost fabric-tools]$ sudo npm install -g composer-cli
[sudo] password for srisris: 
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
/usr/bin/composer -> /usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ composer-cli@0.19.1
updated 1 package in 23.255s
[srisris@localhost fabric-tools]$ npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.6.0 node/v9.11.0 linux x64"

; userconfig /home/srisris/.npmrc
prefix = "/home/srisris"

; node bin location = /usr/bin/node
; cwd = /home/srisris/hyperledger/fabric-tools
; HOME = /home/srisris
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

[srisris@localhost fabric-tools]$ npm ls -g --depth=0
/home/srisris/lib
├── node-gyp@3.6.2
└── rebuild@0.1.2

[srisris@localhost fabric-tools]$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperledger Composer is supported for Mac and Ubuntu, but some people have it running on Centos.

It looks like you have installed composer-cli with sudo, and it is installed under `/usr/lib`,  BUT when you look for it using the npm ls -g -depth=0 command you are NOT using sudo and it is looking under `/home/srisris/lib`

If you do `sudo npm ls -g -depth=0` you should see it.

Under Ubuntu it is recommended that you do not use sudo to install and run Composer.   This link from the [Composer Knowledge Wiki](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#installissues) might help with any npm access issues.

Comment: I tried without Sudo to install too, but it didnt. I am really confused. And you are right, I can see Composer-Cli with I checked ls -g with sudo on. But I keep getting this error [srisris@localhost fabric-tools]$ ./createPeerAdminCard.sh 
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv11
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

No version of composer-cli has been detected, you need to install composer-cli at v0.19 or higher